# How to change number of vertices for cylinder after created it?

Tags: vertices

I've created a cylinder object which is fine at first. But as modeling goes by I've decided to change some properties,like number of vertices, of the cylinder just to see it in real-time. But cannot find the solution.
Search the internet only come up as using "Adjust Last operation". I know I can just add new one. But for the sake of knowledge and future work flow.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do it more or less manually.
Two ways come to mind.

**01)** Screw Modifier - when your mesh has a uniform profile (Eg. greek columns, wheel rims)

[image]

**02)** To sphere function - when you run out of options :)

- Add loopcuts and use *Mesh > Transform > To Sphere* to correct the the circles

[image]