# How might I smooth the outside faces in this model (STL), using blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm interested in using the following model (https://www.dropbox.com/s/suhmrr8yoleyppi/02-right-cylincer-repaired.stl?dl=0).

[image]

I'd like to smooth the outer faces (like a subdivide, I guess), but I need that smoothing to be more than just for rendering, as I want to export the STL again and print it.

I've tried selecting some of the faces, splitting them off, and applying various operations to them, but I don't really know blender well so I'm shooting in the dark (and not hitting anything!)

Is this possible in blender?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This answer could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172260/78972

Comment: Use subdiv modifier and object mode smooth shading.